# inject default values into Spring bean with annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, javabeans

I'd like to set default values for a list in a bean using annotations.

For example, if it's not a list you can do:

```
@Value("myValue")
String test;
```

But, in my case i want to give default values for a List of String.

```
List<String> tests;
```

In XML, it's something like that:

```
<bean id="beanId" class="class...">
    <property name="tests">
        <list>
            <value>value 1</value>
            <value>value 2</value>
            <value>value 3</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I wanted to know if there is an existing annotation, or if I have to create one ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@Value` understands expression language, so you can use arbitrary method calls, although the syntax may get ugly, something like this:

```
@Value("#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList('Value 1','Value 2','Value 3')}")
```

**Reference:**

- [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)
- [Annotation based Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-annotation-based)

Answer (score 4):

You can assign default values directly, without any annotations:

```
String test = "myValue";

List<String> tests = Arrays.asList("value 1", "value 2", "value 3");
```

`@Value` is needed when you want Spring to handle values in the same way as in XML file, for example, to evaluate SpEL expressions, resolve placeholders, etc. If you don't need it, you can do assign default values without annotations.

Comment: thank you, indeed i forgot to say that I could need to resolve placeholders.